# math expression Randomly rounding up

Tags: ruby, parsing, rubygems

In the code below 2/5 results to 0.0 instead of 0.4 which should be correct answer

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dentaku' 

expression = '2/5'
calculator = Dentaku::Calculator.new 
result = calculator.evaluate(expression).to_f
puts "#{result}"
```

I am using dentaku to evaluate the the math expression the documentation for this gem can be found here:   https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku/blob/master/README.md

Comment: dividing a `Fixnum` by a `Fixnum` will result in a `Fixnum` you need to convert one of them to a `Float` or better still convert the whole thing to `Rational`. e.g. `expression = Rational.new("2/5")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first stop when searching for an answer to this should have been the official [documentation for `/`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-2F):

> fix / numeric → numeric_result
>
> Performs division: the class of the resulting object depends on the class of numeric and on the magnitude of the result. It may return a Bignum.

For example:

```
3/2 # => 1
(3/2).class # => Fixnum

3/2.0 # => 1.5
(3/2.0).class # => Float
```

Ruby will return a Float if either value is a Float:

```
3.0/2 # => 1.5
(3.0/2).class # => Float
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Dentaku treats division of two integers as integer division. Try `2/5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try expression = '2.0/5.0' instead, maybe your numbers are considered as integers (you want floats) because of the missing ".0" and so you get an integer result of zero